# Can I do this with an .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm using a host that will only allow PHP files to be located in a subdir called `/cgi/`

But now all my links are `/cgi/..`

Excuse my daftness, but can I write a rewrite in my .htaccess file to make the site think that `/cgi/` is the root so that all my links and the site itself appears to be in the root?

This is what I have but its causing a 500 error :

```
# Turn on rewrites.
RewriteEngine on

# Only apply to URLs on this domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thegrancenturions.com$

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi/

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi/$1

# Also redirect the root folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thegrancenturions.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cgi/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Does your host allow rewrites at all? If they're making you put PHP in `/cgi/` I'd be surprised if they let you override much in `.htaccess`...

Comment: Yah they said they would put an HTML file in the root and redirect it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ cgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I've not tested it, but something similar to this ought to work. You may also need to add a `RewriteCond` which checks that incoming requests are not for `/cgi/..`